# How to insert an Image to sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Whenever I try to add an Image to sqlite table it shows null although words are inserted successfully.

Code:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,bos);
            byte[] img=bos.toByteArray();
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put("image", img);
            db.insertImage(cv,editword,editcategory);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Database Scheme:

```
    `String sql = "Insert Into Images (Images, Name, Category) Values ("+cv+", '"+name+"', '"+category+"')";
mDb.execSQL(sql);`
```

Image datatype in that table is Blob

Comment: Could you add the schema of your DB to the question? Specifically what is the data type of the image column?

Comment: @Jeroen I edited the question and added all the information you want

Comment: We usually don't save the image itself in database, we save its location, which would be an `Uri` (local) or an `Url` (web).

Comment: @SamChen No I save them as Blob not their location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by placing:

```
Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

alone in the try-catch clause. I also replaced the:

```
db.insertImage(cv,editword,editcategory);
Toast.makeText(this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

in a new function